# inverse of linear operator not bounded

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Show that the operator $l^{\infty }\rightarrow l^{\infty } $ defined by $y=(\eta _{j})=Tx$, $\eta _{j}=\frac{\xi _{j}}{j}$, $x=\xi _{j}$ has inverse operator not bounded.

I though by continuity, (continuity if and only if is bounded) or can it resolved by continuity in a point?

Comment: A linear operator is continuous iff it is linearly bounded iff it is continuous at each point iff it is continuous at one point.

Answer (score 2):

For linear operators it is sufficient to check continuity at a point, but here we'll check that the inverse is not bounded.

Notice that if $T((x_1, x_2, ... )) = (x_1, \frac{x_2}{2}, ... )$, then

$S(T((x_1, x_2, ...))=(x_1, x_2, ...)$, where $S(x_1, x_2, ...):= (x_1, 2x_2, 3x_3, ...)$.

Then $sup_{\vert \vert x \vert \vert =1}\vert \vert S(x) \vert \vert =\infty$, since for instance $\vert \vert S(e_j) \vert \vert = j$ where $e_j$ is the vector with with a one in the $j^{th}$ spot and zero elsewhere.